# Windows Phone images look blurry but iphone and droid look fine

Tags: html, css, windows-phone

Hi i have run into a problem on a site on windows phone.

When i preview on windows phone most of my images look really blurry but on iphone and droid they look just fine.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: Do you have any CSS effect applied to those images? Also, is the Windows Phone which you are testing your site on high-resolution or is it pixelated?

Comment: i have am using % values for width on the images

Comment: and the resolution on the windows phone is 1089x1920

Comment: Can you see this icon while viewing the page? http://i.imgur.com/kQGkFav.png